# Error couse DataTime-varchar(10)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have database table in which there is a column `OccurDate` of datatype  `DateTime`.

Data is like this...

```
06-03-2013 06:47:49
06-03-2013 16:47:49
```

I have to find InTime,OutTime,WorkDuration.

I am using query like this

```
Min(convert(varchar(10),OccurDateTime,108)) AS InTime,
Max(convert(varchar(10),OccurDateTime,108)) AS OutTime,
```

but I am facing problem while calculating `workDuration` because the

```
workDuration = 16:30:00 - InTime    //16:30:00 means 4:30 pm
```

and Intime is now `varchar(10)` so it cannot subtract from `Datetime`.......

The query that I am using..

```
SELECT UserID AS EmpCode,FirstName,LastName,Department,convert(varchar(10),OccurDateTime,103) AS Date,Min(convert(varchar(10),OccurDateTime,108)) AS InTime,
Max(convert(DateTime,OccurDateTime,108)) AS OutTime,
convert(varchar(10),(Max(convert(DateTime,OccurDateTime,108))- Min(convert(DateTime,OccurDateTime,108))),108) as Work,

FROM TTransactionLog1
WHERE convert(varchar(10),OccurDateTime,103) = '14/03/2013'
GROUP BY UserID, FirstName, convert(varchar(10),OccurDateTime,103),LastName,Department
```

So you guys have any idea......

Comment: why do you need to convert it to varchar?

Comment: Give the full query you are using. At the moment I don't see the sense in converting your times to `VARCHAR`'s

Comment: yes there is no sence..can you tell me how to store only time in Intime

Comment: @KevinBrydon Look at the question now...

Answer (score 2):

You should be looking for `Min/Max Dates` **not** for the `Min/Max of varchar`. So check Dates before converting them to varchar and convert them as the final thing for the required format.

Also you have to use `Datediff` function to get the *`difference of Max and Min dates`* and when you passing string as Dates, please use `ISO format` (*`'yyyymmdd'`*) which is *`NOT culture specific`*. Otherwise your query may not work in servers with different cultural settings.

I think following query should work:

```
SELECT UserID AS EmpCode, FirstName, LastName, Department,
       --Convert(varchar(10), OccurDateTime, 103) AS  Date,
       Convert(varchar(10), Min(OccurDateTime), 108) AS InTime,
       Convert(varchar(10), Max(OccurDateTime), 108) AS OutTime,
       Convert(varchar(10), 
           Datediff(day,Min(OccurDateTime), Max(OccurDateTime)),108) as Work
FROM TTransactionLog1
WHERE OccurDateTime  = '20130314' --Note: ISO format 
GROUP BY UserID, FirstName, --OccurDateTime, 
        LastName, Department
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH A AS (SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '16:25:00') InTime)
SELECT
CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(DATETIME, '16:30:00') - InTime,108) workDuration
FROM A
```

**Output**: `00:05:00`
I believe double convertion will lead you to make `datetime` calculations *first* and `convert` to `varchar` *after*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate an interval between two datetimes, use datediff().